# Is $\{F,+,·\}$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let's assume $\{F,+,·\}$ where every non-zero element of $F$ has two additive inverses.  $\{F,+,·\}$ satisfies all field axioms: closure under + and ·, commutativity, associativity, distributivity, existence of additive and multiplicative identities and multiplicative inverses for every element.

Is $\{F,+,·\}$ a field?

Comment: What do you mean by "*two additive inverses*"?  Additive inverses are unique.  Suppose $-x$ and $-X$ are both additive inverses of $x$.  Then you have $-X = -X + 0 = -X + (x + (-x)) = (-X + x) + (-x) = 0+(-x) = -x$

Comment: If they are not unique, then  $(F,+)$ is not an abelian group, and hence $F$ is not a field.

Comment: I don't think this question deserves such a negative reception. It's a reasonable thing to wonder when first seeing groups/fields/etc., and if the associativity trick doesn't occur to you it's hard to make any sort of progress so I don't see what sort of additional context could have been supplied. It is asked in a slightly weird and brief way, but it's also the poster's first question - I don't think it's that bad.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I didn't downvote, but I think that the downvotes are because the OP has just posted a question without any context or attempts at solving it.

Comment: I agree with the comment of @NoahSchweber and have accordingly voted to reopen the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an apocryphal story in most math departments about a Ph.D. student who wrote a dissertation about a very interesting and new type of mathematical structure.  The dissertation proved a whole bunch of results about the structure and the oral defense was going well until someone asked:  "Can you provide an example of such a structure?"  The student couldn't.  It took the interlocutor about 10 minutes (so the story goes) to prove that the structure couldn't exist.

As the comments demonstrate, it's impossible to create a structure that satisfies all field axioms in which any element (much less all of them) has two additive inverses.  So since no such structure can exist, by vacuity of condition, you can prove anything you like about it.

The point of this answer is that before asking questions about a structure's properties, you should always remember to first ask:  Can this structure exist?  In the case of your question, it can't.

Comment: I like very much your answer. Congratulations !

Comment: [Related.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53122/mathematical-urban-legends/65787#comment131838_53122)